# Hibernate Inner Join Resultlist

Tags: hibernate, join

an inner join and list() in hibernate gives me List where Object is an Object-Array with one Object for each joined enitity.

Is it possible to retrieve a List with just the first entity? i needed the second just for filtering purposes.

And i think it's ugly too loop manual through the list and collect the wanted objects by myselfe

Comment: Could you please be a bit more explicit, by showing the HQL, showing an example of what it returns, and an example of what you would like to return?